# Rails simple_form association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm having a difficult time getting the `:association` helper to work.  Basically I want to have a select box with all 32 teams and instead of an unhelpful `:team_id` number, I want to use ActiveRecord magic to show the 'abbr' or 'city' from the appropriate Team instead. I'm using a MySQL DB btw.

**Models**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players
end
```

**Controller**

```
@player = Player.find(params[:id])
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @player do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :first %>
    <%= f.input :last %>
    <%= f.association :teams %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

==================

Just to help visualize the data here is a sampling of the data as it appears in the database.

**Database - Teams**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id |   city    |   name    |     created_at      |     updated_at      | abbr |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | Arizona   | Cardinals | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | ARI  |
|  2 | Atlanta   | Falcons   | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | ATL  |
|  3 | Baltimore | Ravens    | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | BAL  |
|  4 | Buffalo   | Bills     | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | 2013-08-27 17:23:55 | BUF  |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

**Database - Players**

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | team_id | position | first  |      last       |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       5 | QB       | Derek  | Anderson        | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 | 2013-08-27 20:41:37 |
|  2 |      24 | QB       | Matt   | Barkley         | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 |
|  3 |      18 | QB       | McLeod | Bethel-Thompson | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 |
|  4 |       6 | QB       | Matt   | Blanchard       | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 |
|  5 |      26 | QB       | Sam    | Bradford        | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 | 2013-08-26 18:48:59 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should be using singular for `belongs_to`, not plural. So your model becomes

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

...and your form input also in the singular, with `abbr` as the displayed field in your select and `id` as the actual value that's passed on to your params:

```
<%= f.association :team, :label_method => :abbr, :value_method => :id
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the plural problem, lots of variables for this noob ;)  Theres two issues Im still wrestling with, you might be able to help.  1. Its not updating the object correctly (it was working with :team_id) and 2. I'd like to change it from Team.name (default) to Team.abbr, my attempts aren't working.

Comment: Does this work? `f.association :team, label_method: :abbr, value_method: :id`

Comment: Fixed the second problem. The updating problem is probably elsewhere in the app as the other fields aren't updating. I'll post back when I figure it out.

Comment: The updating bug was a `params.permit()` issue btw.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

pass a label_method.

like

```
<%= f.association :team, label_method: "#{:city} #{:name}" %>
```

better yet, you might already have the full_name functionality in place, just call that

You might have to also use the value_method option and set to team_id to properly set it if simple_form can't properly guess form the passed in association

Comment: I'm getting this error if it helps `uninitialized constant Player::Teams`, the label_method: didn't work unfortunately

Comment: You're getting this error because you should always use singular with `belongs_to`. The method you're supposed to call on `player` is `team`, not `teams`.